# pip install pygtk not working

Tags: python, pygtk

Any ideas as to what this means?  I don't know if this helps, but it seems like most things I try to pip install don't install correctly and I get errors.

```
BenjaminsMacBook:~ OwlFace$ pip install pygtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1
BenjaminsMacBook:~ OwlFace$
```

Answer (score 0):

pygtk install script can't find pip 1.4.1
you have to install pip 1.4.1

Comment: is it possible i could have accidently installed pip inside a virtual environment and that's why i'm getting this?

Comment: because I've definitely installed pip before.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857672/osx-mavericks-broken-pip-and-virtualenv). Basically, to fix it, run:

```
easy_install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a Dependency of pip `required version = 1.4.1`,

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

if no output here probably you dont have pip installed

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

if your version is not 1.4.1, update pip

Your error shows that you have pip installed, so check the version

```
    BenjaminsMacBook:~ OwlFace$ pip install pygtk
    Traceback (most recent call last):
===>    File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
```

For pip1.4.1 visit: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/